# Why I got Deployment failed on the following stages XXX due to an undefined error occurred while attempting to connect to the server Azure DevOPS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

On Azure DevOPS, I got the error below:
Deployment failed on the following stages UAT. An undefined error occurred while attempting to connect to the server. Status code 0: error.

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution to use another browser. First, Brave was getting errors. In stead of Brave, I have opened chrome with a clean history and catch. It worked for me.